# stripe payment issue ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment, stripe-payments

So I have made a stripe payment option in my app. When I click the button pay now, it shows me that the payment is successful. and when I go to my stripe account and go to stripe-test and check logs, I can see my test payment with the code 200 OK. But this payment doesn't show in stripe-test events, or in stripe-test payments. Are the payments from logs processed the next day or am I doing something wrong?

```
def charge
  Stripe.api_key = "some_test_api_key"
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id)

  if stripe_customer_id.nil?
    Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => 2500,
      :currency => "cad",
      :customer => stripe_customer_id,
      :description => "Usage charges for #{name}"
    )
  end
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message
    errors.add :base, "Unable to process charge. #{e.message}."
    false
  end
```

Comment: Giving a little big more of context and code can help here.

Comment: def charge
     Stripe.api_key = "some_test_api_key"
     customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id)
     if stripe_customer_id.nil?
       Stripe::Charge.create(
         :amount => 2500,
         :currency => "cad",
         :customer => stripe_customer_id,
         :description => "Usage charges for #{name}"
   ) 
       
     end
   rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
     logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message
     errors.add :base, "Unable to process charge. #{e.message}."
    false
  end

this is my method

Comment: I get everything I should in a log

Comment: To charge a credit card, you create a new charge object. If your API key is in test mode, the supplied card won't actually be charged, though everything else will occur as if in live mode. (Stripe assumes that the charge would have completed successfully). -> I found this in documentation... Does this means my code works, or should the test payment show in the payments section nontheless?

Comment: I don't have a webhook set up, is that why it doesn't show in events and payments?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the 'card' parameter when creating that `Charge` object?

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: As you posted your code, you're only making the charge if the customer **does not** exist. (If `stripe_customer_id` is nil.) Is that how it's written in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only executing if the `stripe_customer_id` is `nil`. What you want is the opposite, `!stripe_customer_id.nil`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have points to leave comments, so I have to post it like an answer ..
Payments should be processed instantly, so there must be a problem in your request.

Webhooks have no any effect on payments, its just for tracking events on your site.

Please, can you show your request's body and stripe's response? You can check it in logs.

Comment: I was researching a little bit, and is it possible that stripe is not capturing the charge? You have my method in the question, so if you can check..
this is my Parsed Request Query Parameters: card:
name: "undefined"
number: "**** **** **** 4242"
cvc: "***"
exp_month: "1"
exp_year: "2017"
key: "test api key"
callback: "sjsonp1382114814769"
_method: "POST"

Comment: and this is my Response body:
id: tok_2mEtVDbZv6V0ak
livemode: false
created: 1382114851
used: false
object: "token"
type: "card"
card:
id: card_2mEtm950YzGMTo
object: "card"
last4: "4242"
type: "Visa"
exp_month: 1
exp_year: 2017
fingerprint: "IA76WK3FlCblrBeL"
customer: null
country: "US"
name: "undefined"
address_line1: null
address_line2: null
address_city: null
address_state: null
address_zip: null
address_country: null

Comment: I have nothing in: Parsed Request POST Body